# Building a list of all branches in a tree

Tags: haskell, tree

I need to make function returns all possible branches from a tree
with this form:

```
data Tree a = EmptyT | NodeT a ( Tree a ) ( Tree a ) deriving (Show)

everyBranch :: Tree a -> [[a]]
```

I'm not sure how to approach this... xD
I'm still a newbie in Haskell.

Let's say that I have:

```
            1
           / \
          2   3
         /\  / \
        4  5 7  8
```

I want to get: `[[1,2,4], [1,2,5], [1,3,8], [1,3,7]]`

Answer (score 6):

We'll use a recursive approach. Let's start with a rough skeleton:

```
everyBranch :: Tree a -> [[a]]
everyBranch EmptyT = _something
everyBranch (NodeT v (Tree l) (Tree r)) = _somethingElse
```

Now we'll fill in the holes. (This syntax is known as 'typed holes': if you run the above program through GHC, it will give you an error message with the type of the value which should be in the hole.) Now, I'm not sure about the first case: depending on your need, it could be `[]` (no branches) or `[[]]` (one branch with no elements), so we'll come back to this later. For the second case, we need a way to construct a list of branches given the `v`alue and the `l`eft and `r`ight subtrees. How do we do that? We'll recursively find every branch in the `l`eft tree, and every branch in the `r`ight tree, and then we'll prepend `v` to both:

```
everyBranch :: Tree a -> [[a]]
everyBranch EmptyT = _something
everyBranch (NodeT v l r) = map (v:) $ everyBranch l ++ everyBranch r
```

Now, let's go back to `EmptyT`. Consider a very simple tree: `NodeT 1 EmptyT EmptyT`. In this case, `everyBranch` should return `[[1]]`. Let's invoke `everyBranch` 'by hand' on this tree:

(I use `└→` to mean 'evaluate sub-expression recursively', and `=>` meaning 'expression evaluates to')

```
everyBranch (NodeT 1 EmptyT EmptyT)
=> map (1:) $ everyBranch EmptyT ++ everyBranch EmptyT
   └→ everyBranch EmptyT
      => _something
=> map (1:) $ _something ++ _something
```

So here, we want `map (1:) $ _something ++ _something` to be equal to `[[1]]`. What is `_something`? Well, it turns out that if `_something` is `[]`, then `map (1:) $ [] ++ []` is `[]`, which isn't what we want. On the other hand, if `_something` is `[[]]`, then `map (1:) $ [[]] ++ [[]]` is `[[1], [1]]` - which isn't what we want either. It looks like we need a slightly different approach. What we'll do is, we'll add another case specifically for these sort of trees:

```
everyBranch :: Tree a -> [[a]]
everyBranch EmptyT = _something
everyBranch (NodeT v EmptyT EmptyT) = [[v]]
everyBranch (NodeT v l r) = map (v:) $ everyBranch l ++ everyBranch r
```

Now, if we test this a bit (albeit using some random value for `_something` to stop it from giving us errors), we find that it works for all binary trees. As mentioned though, we still need to figure out that `_something` value. This value will only matter in two cases: empty trees (in which case it will trivially match `EmptyT`), and trees with only one subtree (in which case either `l` or `r` will match `EmptyT`). I will leave it as an exercise for you to determine what value to put there, how it will affect the result, and why it affects it that way.

Answer (score 0):

We can derive and use `Foldable`, to fold into an ad-hoc monoid to do the job:

```
data Tree a = EmptyT
            | NodeT a ( Tree a ) ( Tree a )
            deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable)

data T a = T a                    -- tip
         | N [[a]]                -- node
         | TN (a,[[a]])           -- tip  <> node
         | NN ([[a]],[[a]])       -- node <> node
         deriving Show

instance Monoid (T a) where
    mempty = N []           -- (tip <> node <> node)  is what we actually want
    mappend (T a)  (N as) = TN (a,as)           -- tip  <> node
    mappend (N as) (N bs) = NN (as,bs)          -- node <> node

    mappend (T a) (NN ([],[])) = N ([[a]])      -- tip  <> (node <> node)
    mappend (T a) (NN (as,bs)) = N (map (a:) as ++ map (a:) bs) 

    mappend (TN (a,[])) (N []) = N ([[a]])      -- (tip <> node) <> node
    mappend (TN (a,as)) (N bs) = N (map (a:) as ++ map (a:) bs)

allPaths :: Tree a -> [[a]]
allPaths (foldMap T -> N ps) = ps
```

The `allPaths` function definition uses [`ViewPatterns`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=viewpatterns#extension-ViewPatterns). Testing,

```
> allPaths $ NodeT 1 (NodeT 2 (NodeT 3 EmptyT EmptyT) EmptyT) 
                     (NodeT 5 EmptyT EmptyT)
[[1,2,3],[1,5]]

> allPaths $ NodeT 1 (NodeT 2 (NodeT 3 EmptyT EmptyT) (NodeT 4 EmptyT EmptyT)) 
                     (NodeT 5 EmptyT EmptyT)
[[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,5]]
```

`(tip <> node <> node)` is what we really want, but `<>` is binary, and we don't know (and shouldn't rely on it if we did) the actual order in which the parts will be combined into the whole by the derived definition of `foldMap`,

```
foldMap T EmptyT          ==  N []
foldMap T (NodeT a lt rt) ==  T a <> foldMap T lt <> foldMap T rt
                              -- but in what order?
```

So we "fake", it by delaying the actual combination until all three parts are available.

Or we could forgo the derivation route altogether, use the above laws as the definition of a custom `foldMap` with a ternary combination, and end up with ... the equivalent of the recursive code in the other answer -- much shorter overall, without the utilitarian cruft of one-off auxiliary types that need to be hidden behind module walls, and self-evidently non-partial, unlike what we've ended up with, here.

So maybe it's not so great. I'll post it anyway, as a counterpoint.